# Two succesive animations on uiimageview...one after another

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uiimageview, uiviewanimation

I have an UIImageView _winTextImage...
I want to perform ro succesive animations on the view as go from left to right end of screen then from right end back to the left...but my code only shows the right to left (2nd) animation only....how can i get two animations one after another ..
HERE IS MY CODE

```
-(void)animateWin
{
    CGRect temp=CGRectMake(0,self.view.frame.size.height/2-_winImageView.frame.size.height/2, _winImageView.frame.size.width, _winImageView.frame.size.height);

    _winImageView.frame=temp;

    [UIView beginAnimations : @"Display notif" context:nil];       //ANIMATION 1
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
     temp.origin.x+=self.view.frame.size.width-_winImageView.frame.size.width;
    _winImageView.frame=temp;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [UIView beginAnimations : @"Display notif" context:(__bridge void *)    (_winImageView)];               //ANIMATION 2
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5 ];
    temp.origin.x=0;
    _winImageView.frame=temp;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: use Animation using Blocks first after 4.0 apple provide this. and now your implement method of animation is Deprecated. for more take a look https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void)animateWin {    
     CGRect temp  = CGRectMake(0,(self.view.frame.size.height/2 -_winImageView.frame.size.height/2), _winImageView.frame.size.width, _winImageView.frame.size.height);
_winImageView.frame = temp;
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{
                     _winImageView.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width - _winImageView.frame.size.width), _winImageView.frame.origin.y, _winImageView.frame.size.width , _winImageView.frame.size.height);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                                           delay:0.0
                                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                                      animations:^{
                                          _winImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, _winImageView.frame.origin.y, _winImageView.frame.size.width , _winImageView.frame.size.height);
                                      }
                                      completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                          [self animateWin];
                                      }
                      ];
                     //temp.origin.x = 0;
                 }
     ];
}
```

Comment: @pratys
Actually i have tried this but we cannot assign temp inside that block !!

Comment: try my edited answer. block variables should be using __block

Comment: this works ! ok...
But i need a good code i cant loop through one after another...can you suggest more discreet one?

Comment: There is no looping here at all.After completion of first animation second one will occur.

Comment: do you want one animation happen after other continuously?

Comment: yes also i mean i need looping ...the effect is the same ...but need more discreet code!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36648/discussion-between-raon-and-pratyusha-terli)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with Apple Animation block.
Please avoid to take to many variables.
please find below & let me know if you want anything else

```
-(void)ImgFrom_L2R_AND_R2L {
animateImg.frame=CGRectMake(320,animateImg.frame.origin.y, animateImg.frame.size.width, animateImg.frame.size.height);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     nimateImg.frame=CGRectMake(-320,animateImg.frame.origin.y, animateImg.frame.size.width, animateImg.frame.size.height);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                                           delay:0.0
                                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                      animations:^{
                                          nimateImg.frame=CGRectMake(320,animateImg.frame.origin.y, animateImg.frame.size.width, animateImg.frame.size.height);
                                      }
                                      completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                                      }
                      ];

                 }
 ];
```

}